# Don't skip empty leading rows when using readxl

Tags: r, readxl

`Read_excel()` function automatically skips leading empty rows. Is there a way to avoid this as I need the row.names in R to correspond with row numbers in excel?

It is impossible to satisfy this objective when I am unaware how many leading rows were skipped by read_excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `range` argument of the `read_excel` function as the documentation for this argument of the function says:

> A cell range to read from, as described in cell-specification.
>   Includes typical Excel ranges like "B3:D87", possibly including the
>   sheet name like "Budget!B2:G14", and more. **Interpreted strictly, even
>   if the range forces the inclusion of leading or trailing empty rows or
>   columns**. Takes precedence over skip, n_max and sheet.

Additionally, you might want to set `col_names = FALSE`, such that the row-numbering stays the same.

Comment: @jan-glx What exactly does not work for you? Does the function call throw errors? Does it not give you the required output? I am asking 'cause the `range` argument is still available `read_excel` in `readxl` version 1.2.0.

Comment: I had a file in which the first column of every second row empty. With and without the range argument only the rows in which the first column was not empty was read by `read_exel`. Might have to do with merged cells though.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know in advance what cells might be missing/available, you can use:

```
readxl::read_excel(path, col_names = FALSE,
                   range = cellranger::cell_limits(ul =c(1L, 1L)))
```

This will read all cells.  It specifies the upper-left `ul` corner of the desired cell range and automatically picks the bottom right.